# Spellchecking multiple files with vim

Tags: spell-checking

I want to spellcheck a bunch of files with vim, so I run:

```
for a in *.txt
do
  vim -c 'set spell' $a
done
```

Now, in each file, I use `]s` to find the next unknown word, and fix the typo or add it to my dictionary; and when I'm done I close the current file with `ZZ` and the next one automatically opens.

That's fine, but for the vast majority of files, there are no typos to report, so I end up doing a lot of `ZZ`, `ZZ`, `ZZ`, etc. It would be better if I could somehow do the following: start vim, but if there are no words in the file that the spellchecker doesn't know about, exit immediately. That way I wouldn't have to close files where there are no changes to make.

**Is there a way to run vim and immediately exit when the spellchecker has no complaint about the file?**

Comment: A simple version might attempt `]s` and, if the cursor doesn’t move, quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script to look for a misspelled word and to quit Vim if it doesn't exist might look like:

```
fun! SpellNext()
    " Go to start of buffer and enable spell checking.
    normal! gg
    set spell

    " Record cursor position.
    let l:pos = getpos('.')

    " Special case: first word is misspelled.
    if spellbadword()[1] isnot# ''
        return
    endif

    " Try to find a misspelled word.
    normal! ]s

    " No more words left if the position is unchanged from last
    " time, so quit Vim.
    if getpos('.') == l:pos
        quit
    endif
endfun
```

As an extra bonus this will also put your cursor on the first misspelled word.

You can load this script when Vim starts with the `-S` commandline flag, and call the function with `-c`:

```
$ vim -S spell.vim  -c ":call SpellNext()" file
```

---

All of that being said; it is probably easier to load multiple files in one go:

```
vim -p *.txt
```

And then call this on every tab:

```
:tabdo :call SpellNext()
```

Which will close all the tabs without spelling errors.

You can probably also do the same with buffers; but I'm in the "use-tabs-as-buffers" crowd, so I don't know how to do that from the top of my head >_<

Comment: This works fine, thanks a lot! The only downside to the first solution is that the terminal blinks each time that vim is opened and closed, but I guess this can't be avoided. :) I'll consider the second solution (which avoids this issue).